# Is there a C*-algebra whose Pedersen ideal is not proper?

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, ideals

In [1, 5.6.3] Pedersen states without proof or reference that there are non-unital C*-algebras whose Pedersen
ideal is the whole algebra.

- Does anyone know where can I find such an example?
- Is it possible to characterize algebras with this property?

---

[1] *Pedersen, Gert K.*, C*-algebras and their automorphism groups, London Mathematical Society Monographs. 14. London - New York -San Francisco: Academic Press. X, 416 p. $ 60.00 (1979). [ZBL0416.46043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0416.46043).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examples include all non-unital algebraically simple $C^\ast$-algebras. By [Blackadar, Bruce E.; Cuntz, Joachim The structure of stable algebraically simple C∗-algebras. Amer. J. Math. 104 (1982), no. 4, 813–822.] a simple, stable $C^\ast$-algebra is algebraically simple if and only if it contains an infinite projection. So an explicit example would be a stabilised Cuntz algebra $\mathcal O_n \otimes \mathcal K$.

Addon: in his original paper [Pedersen, Gert Kjaergȧrd, Measure theory for C∗ algebras. Math. Scand. 19 (1966), 131–145], Pedersen gives the following example of a non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ with $\mathrm{Ped}(A) = A$: Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space, and let $A$ be the $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ of operators whos range projection project onto a separable subspace of $H$. This $C^\ast$-algebra is non-unital and $\mathrm{Ped}(A) = A$. To see this, let $a\in A$ and $p$ be the range projection of $a$. Then $p\in \mathrm{Ped}(A)$ and $a = pa \in \mathrm{Ped}(A)$ since $\mathrm{Ped}(A)$ is an ideal.

Comment: Great answer, as always!

Comment: Thanks Jamie!  I guess I edited my question at the exact same time you posted your answer.  So I wonder if you have an answer to the second part?

Comment: Another minor point:  Pedersen's book predates the reference you mentioned by 3 years, so it might be interesting to know  what was the example he had in mind.

Comment: I don't know how you would characterise this property. If $A$ is stable, has a strictly positive element (e.g. $A$ separable), and the primitive ideal space $Prim(A)$ is compact, the following are equivalent: (i) $Ped(A) = A$, (ii) $A$ contains a properly infinite, full projection, (iii) the only (possibly unbounded) tracial functional on $Ped(A)$ is the zero functional. The proof is essentially the same as the Blackadar-Cuntz result is cited above.
Otherwise I don't know how one could characterise this property.

Comment: Thanks for the addon.  It is a lot easier to understand than the stabilization of the Cuntz algebra!